# Show all text of a docx in a stringBuilder with docx4j

Tags: docx, docx4j

i need to put all text of a docx in a stringBuilder, also with tab and hyphen. 
i've tried the use of org.docx4j.TextUtils, but in the resultant string doesn't seen tab.

```
String inputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "test.docx";   
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
org.docx4j.wml.Document wmlDocumentEl = (org.docx4j.wml.Document)documentPart.getJaxbElement();
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
extractText(wmlDocumentEl, out);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my answer at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/is-it-possible-to-extract-all-text-also-tab-and-hyphen-t1996.html#p6933?sid=b0d58fec2ba349d0f3f49cf66411397c

The problem with tab and hyphen, as I guess you know, is that they aren't represented in the docx as normal characters.

Tab is w:tab

A hyphen might be a hyphen character, or it might be displayed (without being actually in the docx), or it might be:

http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/noBreakHyphen.html

or http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/softHyphen.html

Replicating Word's hyphenation behaviour would be a challenge.

But for the others, there are three approaches which occur to me:

1. generalising your traverse approach (are you using TraversalUtil.getChildrenImpl?)
2. doing it in XSLT (you can do this in docx4j, but XSLT is probably slower, and a mix of technologies)
3. marshal the main document part to a string, do suitable string replacements, then unmarshal, then use TextUtils

For (3), assuming MainDocumentPart mdp, to get it as a String:

```
String stringContent = mdp.getXML();
```

Then to inject the modified content:

```
mdp.setContents((Document)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(stringContent) );
```

Comment: hi Jason, i'm using the (1.) approach, getContent().getChildren and analize all children ( instanceof Run, sdtBlock, text R.Tab, R.SoftHyphen ecc.. ) but it's difficult, because i've to handle many document and every document have a difference structure, so i've i've fear to don't generalize well. I'm more interesting in the (3.) approach because, i've to search in the document how many instance of a word. So how can i marshall the main document to a string? does it marshall also Tab?

Comment: i've tried the third approach but i've seen that it marshall the xml structure in the string, so it's not ok for me because the word  fragmentation accross run. I think the first method is better, have you got any tips to generalize the traverse approach?

Comment: With the third approach, you still use TextUtils as your final step, after which the word fragmentation/split runs shouldn't be apparent.

Comment: What method of TextUtils should i use? extractText? this question because i've to find also word with tab (i.e. pippo\t) and extract test don't print "tab" character.

Comment: In your string replacement, you'll need to convert w:tab to something other than the tab character, and after TextUtils, convert that special character sequence to the tab character.